Ackermann function in the Lambda Calculus
I'm trying to write a hyperoperation function in lambda calculus.
It's usually written as ackermann(a,b,n) but for partial application purposes I think it makes more sense to put n first. As such, I'm calling it \textswab{A}k n a b.
Arithmetic operations on numbers can be represented by functions over Church numerals. These functions can be defined in \lambda-calculus or implemented in most functional programming languages. To begin adding numbers, we need a function that defines the successor numeral, similar to the increment operation in natural numbers. This function is called the increment function and is denoted by \textswab{S}^+, which in lambda calculus is represented by the following term:
\textswab{S}^+ n f x = f (n f x)

\textswab{S}^+ \textit{ } \Cc{0_\mathbb{N}} = \Cc{1_\mathbb{N}}

Proof:
\textswab{S}^+ \textit{ } \Cc{0_\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow_\beta (\lambda n . \lambda f . \lambda x . f (n f x) ) \space ( \lambda f.\lambda x. x) \rightarrow_\eta \lambda f. \lambda x.f( (\lambda f.\lambda x. x) f x) \rightarrow_\beta \lambda f. \lambda x.f((\lambda x.x)x) \rightarrow_\beta \lambda f. \lambda x.f x \rightarrow_\alpha \Cc{1_\mathbb{N}}

It is easy to show this for any Church numeral, \textswab{S}^+ \textit{ } \Cc{n_\mathbb{N}} = \Cc{n+1_\mathbb{N}}.
Proof:
\textswab{S}^+ \textit{ } \Cc{n_\mathbb{N}} = \rightarrow_\beta (\lambda n . \lambda f . \lambda x . f (n f x) ) \space (\lambda f.\lambda x. f^n x) \rightarrow_\eta \lambda f. \lambda x.f( (\lambda f.\lambda x. f^n x) f x) \rightarrow_\beta \lambda f. \lambda x.f (\lambda x. f^n x) x \rightarrow_\beta \lambda f.\lambda x. f^{n+1} x \rightarrow_\alpha \Cc{n+1_\mathbb{N}}

Now, using this increment function, we can define the addition of two numbers. The addition function \textswab{P}^+ takes two numbers x and y. The result is a function that takes f and x and returns xf(yfx). This can be expressed as follows:
\textswab{P}^+ x y \textit{ } = y \textswab{S}^+ x

\textswab{P}^+ \Cc{x_\mathbb{N}} \Cc{y_\mathbb{N}} \textit{ } = \Cc{{y+x}}_{\mathbb{N}}

\textswab{P}^+ x y \textit{ } = \Cc{y_\mathbb{N}} \textswab{S}^+ \Cc{x_\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow_\beta (\lambda f.\lambda n.f^y n) \textit{ } \textswab{S}^+ \Cc{x_\mathbb{N}} 
    \rightarrow_\beta (\lambda f.\lambda n. f^y n) \textit{ } (\lambda n . \lambda f . \lambda x . f (n f x) ) \Cc{x_\mathbb{N}} \rightarrow_\beta {\textswab{S}^{+}}^y \textit{ } \Cc{x_\mathbb{N}} 
    \rightarrow_{\eta\beta} \hdots \rightarrow_{\eta\beta} \lambda f.f^y f^x x \rightarrow_\alpha \lambda f. f^{y+x}  x \rightarrow_\alpha \Cc{{y+x}}_{\mathbb{N}}

Since the correctness of \textswab{S}^+ has been proven, the correctness of \textswab{P}^+ is also proven.
After addition, naturally, we construct multiplication:
Multiplication: \textswab{M}^+ x y \textit{ } = y (\textswab{P}^+ x) \textit{ } \Cc{0_\mathbb{N}}

And exponentiation:
Exponentiation: \textswab{M}^* x y \textit{ } = y (\textswab{M}^+ x) \textit{ } \Cc{1_\mathbb{N}}

Tetration is a hyperoperation that follows addition, multiplication, and exponentiation. In the hierarchy of hyperoperations, tetration is the fourth in sequence and is usually denoted as superscripts or powers. Tetration of x to y is denoted as ^y x or x \uparrow \uparrow y and is defined as x raised to the power of itself y times. Formally, this can be written as:
^y x = x \uparrow \uparrow y = x^{x^{x^{.^{.^{.^x}}}}}

where the exponentiation of x repeats y times. For example, tetration of 3 to 2 (i.e., ^2 3) would look like this: ^2 3 = 3^{3} = 27; for ^3 2 = 2^{2^{2}} = 2^{4} = 16.
Tetration: \textswab{M}^{*^2} x y \textit{ } = y (\textswab{M}^* x) \textit{ } \Cc{1_\mathbb{N}}
A hyperoperation depends on the previous hyperoperation: \textswab{M}^{^{n}} x y \textit{ } = y (\textswab{M}^{^{n-1}} x) \textit{ } \Cc{1_\mathbb{N}}
Primitive recursion (which we will refer to as induction for our purposes) is an important concept in lambda calculus, allowing the definition of functions through recursion without using recursive \lambda-terms. It is expressed using a combinator that returns a function obtained via primitive recursion from given data.
\textswab{I}nduction = \lambda f_0 \textit{ } h \textit{ } \Cc{n_\mathbb{N}}. \textit{ } Snd \textit{ } (\Cc{n_\mathbb{N}} \textit{ } (C I (\lambda k \textit{ } f_k. [\textswab{S}^+ k, \textit{ } h \textit{ } k \textit{ } f_k])) [\Cc{0_\mathbb{N}}, \textit{ } f_0])$,

where
[A,B] is a pair and [A,B]_1 \textit{ } = \textit{ } Fst, \textit{ } [A,B]_2 \textit{ } = \textit{ } Snd — the first and second components, respectively.
f_0 is the value of the computed function at 0. h is the transition function. \Cc{n_\mathbb{N}} is the numeral for which we compute f(n). Snd is used without the pair because inside we apply a function that transforms pairs n times to the pair (0, f(0)).
\lambda-definable functions are closed under primitive recursion with properties:
f(0) = f_0 and f(k+1) = h(k, f(k)).
Proof:
To prove by induction on n, we will show that for each natural number, the following statements hold:
1.
n + 1 (T, (0, f_0)) \rightarrow_\beta (n + 1, f(n + 1))





f(n + 1) \rightarrow_\beta h(n, f(n))

Proof of the first statement:
n + 1 (T, (0, f_0)) \rightarrow_\beta T((n, (T, (0, f_0)))) 
    \rightarrow_\beta T((n, f(n))) 
    \rightarrow_\beta (n + 1, h(n, f(n))) 
    \rightarrow_\beta (n + 1, f(n + 1))

For the second statement:
f(n + 1) \rightarrow_\beta (n + 1 (T, (0, f_0)))_1 
    \rightarrow_\beta (T((n, (T, (0, f_0))))_1 
    \rightarrow_\beta (T((n, f(n))))_1 
    \rightarrow_\beta ((n + 1, h(n, f(n))))_1 
    \rightarrow_\beta h(n, f(n))

The structure of the sequence will look as follows:
(0, f(0)) \rightarrow (1, f(1)) \rightarrow (2, f(2)) \rightarrow \dots \rightarrow (n, f(n))
Question: How can I use induction on the Ackermann function to extend these hyperoperations within lambda calculus? Are there specific strategies for formulating higher hyperoperations through primitive recursion, or is there a combinator that can help handle this?

This might be easier to read if you consider using Mathjax (e.g., $x \rightarrow y$) rather than code (x \rightarrow y).
